# Formatting date in Oracle without knowing original format beforehand

Tags: oracle

I have a table that stores dates in a VARCHAR field. There are a couple of formats that are stored in that field:

```
DD-MMM-YY
```

and

```
MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss
```

and perhaps a few more as data comes into the table from different sources.

I have a function that retrieves those and I need to reformat those to be in the same format before returning from the function. How can I accomplish that without knowing beforehand the exact format of the date?

Answer (score 3):

> I have a table that stores dates in a VARCHAR field

Change the VARCHAR2 to a DATE.

Then you can store any valid date value, regardless of incoming format you want, and do any DATE operation against it.

Any other solution going forward where your DATEs are stored as anything other than a DATE, will only lead to more problems.

Exceptions being you need fractions of a second (TIMESTAMP) or you need a Timezone (TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE)

Comment: that is what I wanted to do. Unfortunately the decision is not up to me

Comment: Doesn't mean it's not the right answer, especially for anyone else coming here with a similar scenario :)

Comment: Incidentally, “change the VARCHAR2 to a DATE” is exactly the problem at the heart of this question…

Comment: @jackohug right, it'd be good to know how many date format models are actually being stored in the column, then you'd need to build an api to populate table going forward that enforced the data coming in as a date

Comment: @thatjeffsmith and to be thorough hunt down the person that created the problem in the first place and prevent it from happening again!

Answer (score 1):

Not easily. You'll, basically, have to know all formats used. How? Step-by-step. Start with the most obvious ones (those you already mentioned; note that minutes format mask is `mi`, not `mm` (which is for months)).

That query will fail many times - as many as there are "errors" you didn't catch yet.

`REGEXP_LIKE` might help as you can decide whether certain format matches mask you used, but - there's nothing much you can do when converting "valid" format,  e.g. `4 digits-two digits-two digits two digits:two digits:two digits` such as `2019-87-54 69:74:84` (`yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss`) to a valid date as there's obviously no month 87 nor day 54 nor hour 69 etc.

So, take your time, go step-by-step, test frequently.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `CASE` statement and `REGEXP_LIKE` to match different patterns:

```sql
SELECT CASE
         WHEN REGEXP_LIKE( your_column, '^\d{1,2}[ \/-](JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)[ \/-]\d{4}$', 'i' )
         THEN TO_DATE( your_column, 'dd mon yyyy' )
         WHEN REGEXP_LIKE( your_column, '^\d{1,2}[ \/-](JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)[ \/-]\d{2}$', 'i' )
         THEN TO_DATE( your_column, 'dd mon yy' )
         WHEN REGEXP_LIKE( your_column, '^(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])[ \/-](0?[1-9]|1[0-2])[ \/-]\d{4}$' )
         THEN TO_DATE( your_column, 'dd mm yyyy' )
         WHEN REGEXP_LIKE( your_column, '^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])[ \/-](0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])[ \/-]\d{4}$' )
         THEN TO_DATE( your_column, 'mm dd yyyy' )
         WHEN REGEXP_LIKE( your_column, '^(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])[ \/-](0?[1-9]|1[0-2])[ \/-]\d{2}$' )
         THEN TO_DATE( your_column, 'dd mm rr' )
         WHEN REGEXP_LIKE( your_column, '^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])[ \/-](0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])[ \/-]\d{2}$' )
         THEN TO_DATE( your_column, 'mm dd rr' )
         ELSE NULL
       END AS your_column_date
FROM   your_table
```

Expand it to add different patterns, if you need to include times as well.

But the best solution is to stop using strings and use a `DATE` data type to store date values and force your users to use a consistent format when inputting data otherwise you will have issues where you have `01-02-03` and it could be 2nd January 2003, 1st February 2003 or 3rd February 2001 since you don't know if the format is `MM-DD-YY`, `DD-MM-YY` or `YY-MM-DD`.